# How to do search filtering through a collection of arrays?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, advanced-search, searchfiltercollection

I am going to build advance search function in laravel 5. I queried from 'itemregistrations' table by filtering a few fields such as negeriID, categoryID and operasiID. I need to do array map to calculate age value of each item and put in the array. By getting values using itemregistration table and calculating age runs okay but it problem in searching through the if statement. It cannot searching and retrieve the values through the array in the collection.

```
   $newitem = DB::table('itemregistrations')
        ->select('itemregistrations.*')
        ->get();

    //added code to get 'age' value:
    $newitem->map(function ($detail) {

        $detail->age = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y',$detail->lahir_yy)->diffInYears(); 
        return $detail;
    });   


    if ($request->has('negeri_lahir')) {
        $newitem->where('NegeriID', '==', $request->negeri_lahir);
    }

    if ($request->has('kategori')) {
        $newitem->where('CategoryID', $request->kategori);
    }

    if ($request->has('pangkat')) {
        $newitem->where('OperasiID', $request->pangkat);
    }

   dd($newitem->get());
```

The problem because of the array map added, turning the collection in array values causing this error.
It is producing error:

```
 Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

This is the array list in the collection for dd($newitem);

```
 #items: array:1123 [▼
0 => {#709 ▶}
1 => {#680 ▶}
2 => {#681 ▶}
3 => {#712 ▶}

Collection {#671 ▼
#items: array:1123 [▼
0 => {#709 ▼
  +"ItemRegistrationID": 1
  +"COID": 109064
  +"FType": ""
  +"STNo": "0"
  +"RegistrationDate": "2005-12-01"
  and more attributes...
```

How to enable the searching through the array list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, you don't need to use `select()` in query.
2. Looks like better to make filtering in db query using `when()`.

Try:

```
$newitem = DB::table('itemregistrations')
    ->when(request('age'), function($query){
        $query->whereRaw('YEAR(curdate()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('age')]);
    })
    ->when(request('negeri_lahir'), function($query){
        $query->where('NegeriID', request('negeri_lahir'));
    })
    ->when(request('kategori'), function($query){
        $query->where('CategoryID', request('kategori'));
    })
    ->when(request('pangkat'), function($query){
        $query->where('OperasiID', request('pangkat'));
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: sorry, I need to mention that I need to calculate the age before the filtering search because I need to filter for age too

Comment: @joun I corrected my answer. You could try something like this.

Comment: It works well..only the searching of age is not correct..i am not sure it is searching the calculated age or not but the results is not according to the age search..should be age=40 will search age from 40 upwards..thanks

Comment: @joun To clarify, you need age=40 or age>40?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, age =>40, means 40 and above

Comment: Thanks, but looks like the age is not filtered. persons with birth year 1996, 87 included when age field insert is 40

Comment: I got this in console -search:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Sorry, it is an old log...i already refresh and no error..but it doesn't filter age at all..it filters the others but not the age..I tried test with age and without age value, the result is the same.

Comment: I forward this problem to a new question -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910738/why-age-filter-doesnt-filter-the-age-using-sql-query-in-laravel, I accepted your answer as you solve the main problem to include age filter into query without error. Thanks..

Comment: Thank you IndianCoding, my mistake..your code works well..just mistake in variable text name for age..I just noticed..that's why it doesn't get the filtering age figure. But I already accept your answer earlier..Thanks again..