# Why age filter doesn't filter the age using sql query in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, filter

I want to query list of persons based on age. Then, the query will calculate the age using lahir_yy column(birth year value) and search for the list.

```
   $newitem = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->when(request('age'), function($query){
                    $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('age')]);})
   ->get();
```

However, the code doesn't work. It doesn't filter the age but giving no error.

Comment: `request('age')` doesn't throw error? also, where is your closing `}` for the closure function?

Comment: it doesn't throw any eror..I already update the question, closure bracket left behind to be copied.

Comment: Add this ->select(['*', DB::raw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy as age')]), and attach results of  `dd($newitem)`.

Comment: sorry for late reply..going away for a while.. I had tried the above code, it add age in the array list.

Comment: Thank you IndianCoding, I already tried and check again the code..I just notice that the variable for age text field is different..once I changed that, your code works well...thank you so much and sorry for not noticed the mistakes earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with small change. Send `request('age')` in closure. Hope this will work.

```
$newitem = DB::table('itemregistrations')
            ->when(request('age'), function($query){
                return $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('age')]);})
->get();
```

Comment: `reuqest()` is not variable, `request()` is global helper function. You can't (it will throws error) and don't need to send function in closure.

Comment: @IndianCoding Thanks did not think of that. So I guess there is missing ```return``` keyword in closure query.

Comment: Ok, the same situation) You don't need to use return here.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution..Prashant